# What is the correct way to inject variables in a DBT model config block?

Tags: jinja2, dbt

Trying to inject an environmental variable in a model config block results in the string being rendered as a constant

```
{{
    config(
        materialized='incremental',
        schema='my_schema',
        database= 'MYDB_{{env_var("ENVIRONMENT")}}',
        transient=False
    )
}}
```

as in

```
Database error while listing schemas in database "MYDB_{{env_var("ENVIRONMENT")}}"
```

What is the correct way to inject env_vars in the config model block?

Comment: https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/dont-nest-your-curlies don't nest your culies. database= 'MYDB_' + env_var("ENVIRONMENT") should do the trick

Comment: Even better would be to put your configuration into a a separate project level yml file.